# Is there a code that can replace document.write()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, forms

This code displays the error window when an error occurs after `submit()`.
I'm using `document.write()` for printing pop-up window (when no error occurred). Because Ajax return data is a whole jsp code include the <html> tag (Spring's ModelAndView).

The code works well in `Chrome` but very slowly in `IE 11` and does not work in `IE 9`. Is there any way to improve performance?

here is code:

```
var popupWindow;

var MyUtil = {
        mySubmit : function(id, name) {
                var Future = "resizable=no,scrollbars=no";
                popupWindow = window.open("", "mypopup", Future);

                var $form = $("<form id='myForm'></form>");
                $form.appendTo("body");

                var item1 = "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+id+"'/>";
                var item2 = "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='"+name+"'/>";
                $form.append(item1).append(item2);

                MyUtil.setPopupSubmitToAjax(popupWindow, $form, '/common/popup.do', 'POST');
                $form.submit();
        },

        setPopupSubmitToAjax : function(newWindowObj, submitForm, url, ajaxType) {
                submitForm.submit(function(e) {
                        $.ajax({
                                url : url,
                                type : ajaxType,
                                target : newWindowObj.name,
                                data : submitForm.serialize(),
                                success : function(data) {
                                        newWindowObj.document.write(data); // here
                                        newWindowObj.focus();
                                        newWindowObj.document.close();
                                },
                                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        newWindowObj.close();
                                        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                                }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                });
        }
};
```

Comment: `target : newWindowObj.name,`?  It is not in the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - submitForm is some kind of plugin?

Comment: `newWindowObj.name` is `mypopup`,  `submitForm` is `$form`. These are from mySubmit function. It does not use another plugin.

Comment: I know `innerHTML` is recommended, but the output data contains scripts such as css and `$(document).ready()` and cannot be used. Is there another alternative?